# Is there a better way to find the polynomial equation for this curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-curves

Consider the curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by the equation
$$
x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} + (xy)^{1/3} = 1,
$$
where $x^{1/3}$ denotes the real cube root of $x$, etc.

Since the equation above involves only algebraic operations, this curve ought to be a branch of an [algebraic curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve), i.e. a curve defined by a polynomial equation involving $x$ and $y$.  I know of only one algorithm to find this equation:

1. Compute the minimum polynomial of $x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} + (xy)^{1/3} - 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$.  Since $\mathbb{Q}(x^{1/3},y^{1/3})$ has degree $9$ over $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$, the minimum polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Q}(x,y)[t]$ presumably has degree $9$, so this will involve computing and then row reducing a $9\times 10$ matrix over $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$.
2. The "constant term" of $p$ will be a rational function in $x$ and $y$ whose numerator is a polynomial $q(x,y)$.  Then the given curve is a branch of the algebraic curve defined by the equation $q(x,y)=0$.

Is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Where does $a$ appear ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Here $a$ was a dummy variable meant to clarify the notation.  I have edited the question to try to state this more clearly.

Comment: very interesting, since the element is integral over Q[x,y], the constant term of minimal polynomial is indeed in Q[x,y]. I am curious that if the constant polynomial always irreducible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon=e^{2\pi i/3}$. Your equation will be
$$
\prod_{k=0}^2 \prod_{\ell=0}^2
\Big( \varepsilon^k x^{1/3} + \varepsilon^\ell y^{1/3} +  \varepsilon^{k+\ell} (xy)^{1/3} -1 \Big) =0.
$$

Comment: The upper bounds for $k$ and $\ell$ should be $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $K = \mathbf{Q}(\zeta_3)$. You could just directly take the norm of the element $x^{1/3} + y^{1/3} + x^{1/3}y^{1/3} - 1$ from $K(x^{1/3}, y^{1/3})$ down to $K(x, y)$. This norm is computed as the product of 9 Galois conjugates of your element and will be an element of $\mathbf{Q}(x, y)$. Should be very easy to do in any computer algebra system which can work with 3rd roots of 1.

But this is just exactly the same as what you suggest!

Comment: Are there faster ways to compute either the Galois conjugates or the norm?  Basically, is there any way to do this by hand, or do I have to rely on a CAS?

Answer (score 2):

Two automated approaches.  With Gröbner basis: see the first entry of [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=groebnerbasis+%7Ba%2Bb%2Ba+b-1%2C+a%5E3-c%2C+b%5E3-d%7D&x=0&y=0) result.  With resultants: first compute [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant+%5Ba%2Bb%2Ba+b-1%2C+a%5E3-c%2C+a%5D&x=0&y=0) and then [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=resultant%5B1-3+b%2B3+b%5E2-b%5E3-c-3+b+c-3+b%5E2+c-b%5E3+c%2C+b%5E3-d%2C+b%5D&x=0&y=0).